# Program to move unlocked files to an new folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

i need something that will move files from one folder to another network location, but leave any locked files that are currently being written to!

any ideas?

apols i am no developer, but i have been trying to use

ROBOCOPY C:\test c:\test\q /move  /R:0 /W:0

but even if i open a file, it still moves it to the new directory

mal

Comment: Show us your code.  Then describe what difficulties you're having and why it doesn't work.  *(surely, you are not asking us to write your code for you?)*

Comment: If you really want code to check if a file is locked you can use this. `2>nul (>>somefile.doc (call )) && (echo file is not locked) || (echo file is locked)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for %%f in (*) do move %%f destination\%%f` (in a batch file) and just allow each individual invocation of `move` to fail, watching the errors scroll by.

There are also options for making `for %%f` work recursively, though that's a bit involved.

Comment: hi Mike is this using something like robocopy?

Comment: no, `for` is a built-in command in good old `cmd.exe`.  And `move` is a standard windows console command.